# Importing a CSV to Mongo on a server

Tags: mongodb, csv, mongoimport

I am having trouble importing a CSV to a MongoDB instance deployed on a server. I was able to use `mongoimport` to load data to a local instance using the following

```
mongoimport -d Josh -c diagnosis -- type csv --file\\location\name.csv --headerlin -- ignoreblanks
```

I have tried to load data to Mongo located on a server through `cmd`:

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongoimport --host xxx.xx.x.xxx --db Josh -c diagnosis -- type csv --file\\location\name.csv -- headerline --ignoreblanks
```

but I get the following error

```
"Error Parsing Command Line: too many positional options"
```

What does “too many positional options” mean when doing a `mongoexport`?

One posting says it is because of black fields in the CSV, however, the `--ignoreblanks` should take care of blank fields, as it worked on the local instance.

Comment: copy and paste the actual command you're using, the problem probably lies within the command

Comment: Looks like you have extra spaces, use `--type csv` instead of `-- type csv` and so on.

Comment: Thanks guys I figured it out. the --ignoreblanks should be --ignoreBlanks

Answer (score 0):

Please add space after `--file` and no space before `type`

```
C:\Program Files\MongoDB 2.6 Standard\bin>mongoimport --host xxx.xx.x.xxx --db Josh -c diagnosis --type csv --file location\name.csv -- headerline --ignoreblanks
```